# SQL - detecting loops in parent child relations

Tags: sql, loops, parent-child

I have parent child data in excel which gets loaded into a 3rd party system running MS SQL server.  The data represents a directed (hopefully) acyclic graph.  3rd party means I don't have a completely free hand in the schema.  The excel data is a concatenation of other files and the possibility exists that in the cross-references between the various files someone has caused a loop - i.e. X is a child of Y (X->Y) then elsewhere (Y->A->B-X).  I can write vb, vba etc on the excel or on the SQL server db. The excel file is almost 30k rows so I'm worried about a combinatorial explosion as the data is set to grow. So some of the techniques like creating a table with all the paths might be pretty unwieldy.  I'm thinking of simply writing a program that, for each root, does a tree traversal to each leaf and if the depth gets greater than some nominal value flags it.
 Better suggestions or pointers to previous discussion welcomed.

Comment: What would you like to do when a loop is detected?

Comment: Your arbitrary cap of "greater than level X = Problem" may be inaccurate if you do not know or cannot determine maximum valid depth. Is that information available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE to detect loops:

```
with prev as (
    select RowId, 1 AS GenerationsRemoved
    from YourTable
    union all
    select RowId, prev.GenerationsRemoved + 1
    from prev
    inner join YourTable on prev.RowId = ParentRowId
    and prev.GenerationsRemoved < 55
)
select * 
from prev
where GenerationsRemoved > 50
```

This does require you to specify a maximum recursion level: in this case the CTE runs to 55, and it selects as erroneous rows with more than 50 children.

Comment: I'd never heard of CTEs as my DB experience is largely zSeries DB/2.  Thank you for the pointer to them. I think I now have the answer to a number of other questions.

Comment: And found a decent tutorial here 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx
Thanks guys

Comment: Though since the CTE has been running for 3 hours now I think I need to consider alternatives. :-)

Comment: @wudang: Do you have an index on the ParentRowId field?  Also turn on "Show Actual Execution Plan" and see if it suggests any indexes.

Comment: @Andomar - yes both the Parent and Child columns are indexed. I think I'll just have to write some code to load the data in memory as a DAG and traverse it building a path from each leaf and checking each discovered node does not already exist in the path.

Comment: Which RowId does `select RowId, prev.GenerationsRemoved + 1` refer to?  The one from `prev` or the one from `YourTable`?

Comment: Sorry I didn't reply Greg. I got moved to another team and got snowed under the backlog waiting for me.