# Detect loops in hierarchy using SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, common-table-expression, table-per-hierarchy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL - detecting loops in parent child relations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230146/sql-detecting-loops-in-parent-child-relations)

I have a simple table with 2 columns `id` and `parentid`:

```
id    |   parentid
------------------
2         1
3         2
4         3
1         4
```

For example, in the above table, 1 is a child of 1 itself (1->2->3->4->1). How to detect such cases?

Would I require an extra column?

Comment: Sounds recursive,, anyone thinking about CTE?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3230256/1373170